# Why is linear movement relative but rotation is absolute?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, rotation

Rotation,at classical mechanics at least, is always absolute but linear movement is not.

What is the reason for this distinction?

I will add a second question. Why this is not the case in general relativity?

Comment: Can you clarify your question a bit? In the frame of the rotating body, there is no rotation. Do you mean to say that uniform linear motion is immaterial in writing Newton's laws but uniform rotation does make a difference in the equations?

Comment: My guess (I'm not sure what exactly you're asking) is that rotation requires a specific point (in $\mathbb{R}^2$) to be specified (as the origin) (i.e. the point around which the rotation occurs). This corresponds to a vector space, i.e. an absolute frame of reference. Linear movement, on the other hand, corresponds to an affine space, which doesn't require any specific choice of origin, thus a relative frame of reference suffices. Again, just a guess on my part.

Comment: Do you mean that **angular velocity** is absolute? If so that's because circular motion involves acceleration and in Newtonian mechanics acceleration is absolute.

Comment: -1. Unclear. I admire succinct questions and answers, but I think that more explanation is required here. Please also consider providing an authority for your claim that there is a distinction between rotational and translational diplacements, and about "this" not being the case in GR.